# set GridView virtualItmCount property

Tags: gridview, paging, custom-paging

i am working on a simple Paging project with gridview in asp.net 4.5 but

i receive (GridView does not contain a definition `virtualItmCount`

error ?? i have set `AllowPaging=True AllowCustomPaging=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Set property VirtualItemCount of the desired GridView to total number of rows. This is used to calculate the PageCount for pager rendering.

*Just noticed the probably typo? In VirtualItmCount vs. the right one VirtualItemCount*